# ELK reading and storing log4j logs

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-curator

We have around 50 servers from where we get log4j logs. these folder where log4j are writes we have been mounted to a machine where we have Logstash, which pushes these logs into Elasticsearch. It creates a index in Elasticsearch called logstash-2018.06.25 where it stores all log information here in this table. Now I have to delete the old logs, I have read that on internet that delete with query wouldn’t be a good way, rather we should delete it using CURATOR(Elasticsearch). I have read that curator can delete the whole index. How can I configure my logstash so that it creates index based on the date.

So it will create a index/table based on day wise.
So 25-Jun-2018 index would be created on 25-Jun-2018.
Similary  26-Jun-2018 index would be created on 26-Jun-2018.

This way I would be able to drop index on older file, using this approach I would be able to have faster performance of elastic search.

To do this how to configure my logstash so that i can acheive this.

Comment: if you can show your configuration file from `/etc/logstash/conf.d/` ?

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch output plugin you can configure index name as follows:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        ...
    }
}
```